# No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I've been following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-build-your-first-iphone-app/

to try and create a simple iOS 6 app.

However I am receiving an error: `@interface for 'UIAlertView'...`

I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

-(IBAction)showMessage;

@end
```

in my `AppDelegate.h` file and

```
-(IBAction)showMessage
{
    UIAlertView *helloWorldAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"my first app" message:@"hello there world!" delagate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [helloWorldAlert show];
}

@end
```

in my `AppDelegate.m` file

I don't seem to understand what the error indicates, I tried a google search but didn't get any closer to finding a solution, so what have I missed here? What must I fix?

The exact error message:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:'
```

Comment: Does your AppDelegate.m import AppDelegate.h? Does your AppDelegate.m have the `@implementation AppDelegate` line?

Comment: @rmaddy it __does__ import AppDelegate.h i also have have `@implementation AppDelegate`

Comment: Show the complete error/warning message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in this line:

```
UIAlertView *helloWorldAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"my first app" message:@"hello there world!" delagate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Replace `delagate` by `delegate`.

Comment: @fermionoid: No problem, you are welcome. I just wonder why the error message has "delegate" in the selector and not "delagate".